# Converting async/await to promise chaining

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this snippet of code, where I am trying to create a new user, bcrypt the password and trying to save the user in the MongoDB through mongoose.

Is there any way I can change this async/await to promise chaining?

```
user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password,
    email: req.body.email
  });
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
  await user.save();

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();
  res.header("x-auth-token", token).send({
    _id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email
  });
});
```

Comment: You could, but why would you want to? `await` looks cleaner

Comment: We are using promises throughout our (learning) project.

Comment: `async` `await` *is* using promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
  user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password,
    email: req.body.email
  });
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
  .then(pw => { user.password = pw; return user.save(); })
  .then(() => { ...rest of the function here...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with bcrypt salt & hash;

```
const newUser = new User({
  name,
  email,
  password
});

//Create salt & hash
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
  bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save().then(user => {...});
  });
})
```